# How can I drill down a stacked bar chart in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi

How can I drill down a stacked bar chart in powerbi, I read that in axis field I have to use the column which I want to drill through, but it is displaying X-axis 0,1,2,3,4 its not making much sense, can somebody share any example here which you have done so that I can get much more clarity on this.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, add the drilldown columns as the axis columns. Then you're able to drill down using the controls on the top of the bar chart.

For example, in this picture I have selected the Category and SubCatecory as the Axis-fields (the Value-field is selected as the Value-field):
[image: Power BI drilldown example]

At the top of the chart, there are arrows pointing up and down. Using those controls, you can drill down in the hierarchy.

Comment: Hi @Gigga, is there a way to drill down on a field that's not on the axis-fields? I want to drill down on a field which is in the column series, is it possible to do that in Powerbi? Thanks!